# How to send message from class to an activity and backwards

Tags: android, bluetooth, singleton

I create a class ManageConection that handles all bluetooth connections. This class implements the Singleton pattern.

But I have the following problem, do not know how to tell from my class ManageConection to an activity for example that a device connected successfully.

The ManageConection class will use various activities.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a connection callback only to one activity at a time or to all of them at once?

Comment: connection callback with one at a time.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that in several ways:

**1.** Use broadcast receiver.
In your activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do what you need in here
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ManageConection.BROADCAST_FILTER));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

from your `ManageConection` class:

```
public static final String BROADCAST_FILTER = "ManageConection_broadcast_receiver_intent_filter";
```

and now whenever you want to send message you can send `Intent` and every activity how hold receiver with the same filter(`BROADCAST_FILTER`) get the callback:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_FILTER);
   i.putExtra("connection_established", true);
   sendBroadcast(i);
```

**2.** Use `interface`:
Somewhere in your application create an interface. From each activity create an instance of it, and pass it to `ManageConection`:

```
    public interface ManageConection  {
    public void onConnected();
}

private ManageConection mCallback = new ManageConection() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        // callback goes here
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ManageConection.getInstace().setConnectionCallback(mCallback);
}
```

In `ManageConection` set a global variable of your callback and set it in `setConnectionCallback()`:

```
private ManageConection mCallback;

public void setConnectionCallback(ManageConection callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}
```

Now when ever you want to send callback to your activity just do:

```
if(mCallback != null)
    mCallback.onConnected();
```

Comment: can you explain a little more how it works the broadcast. The method sendBroadcast(i) not existe.

Comment: sendBroadcast not exist because i want to send a message from a class to an activity.

Comment: sendBroadcast will work only if you have a context as class variable. That work in the following way: mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could use any of the following ways :

1. If you want to do it Java way Use [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
2. If you wish to do it Android way use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)
3. OR you can use any third party Library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

I know there are more ways , but these are the most Generic approach of them all.

**Update**

Also for loose coupling of components you can take a look at [Event Driven programming for android](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/event-driven-programming-for-android-part-i-f5ea4a3c4eab)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface and use a callback to let the activity know that a device has connected or data is received.

```
public interface BluetoothDeviceListener {
    void onDeviceConnected(int arg1, string arg2); ..<----add arguments you want to pass back
    void onDataReceived(int arg1, string arg2); ..<----add arguments you want to pass back
}
```

In your ManageConnection class

```
ArrayList<BluetoothDeviceListener> listeners = new ArrayList<BluetoothDeviceListener>();

...

public void addBluetoothDeviceListener(BluetoothDeviceListener listener){
    if (!listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeBluetoothDeviceListener(BluetoothDeviceListener listener){
    if (listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

When a device connects:

```
for (BluetoothDeviceListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onDeviceConnected(arg1, arg2);
}
```

When data is received:

```
for (BluetoothDeviceListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onDataReceived(arg1, arg2);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothDeviceListener{

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...
    manageConnection.setDeviceConnectedListener(this);
    ...
}

public void onDeviceConnected(int arg1, string arg2){
   // do whatever you need to do
}

public void onDataReceived(int arg1, string arg2){
   // do whatever you need to do
}
```

All from memory so please excuse typos.

This approach decouples the classes.  The connection manager class has no knowledge of the activities.  It simply calls back to any listeners registered.  Those listeners might be Activities, they might be services.  They might be instances of MySparklyUnicorn.  The server neither knows nor cares.  It simply says "if anyone's interested, a device has connected and here are the details".

Comment: Y dont want only send when is connected. I wanto always, if some data is coming from de class manageconnection, advice the activity.

Comment: OK, well same idea, create a method of the interface called `onDataReceived()`.  I edited the interface definition.